# Why is the tilde ~ not working in Javascript querySelector but works in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

How can I select the sibling of textarea tag `pre` in javascript's `querySelector`? I have been able to select it in CSS using the `~` selector. But that doesn't seem to work in Javascript?

I know I can use the `textarea.parentNode.querySelector('pre'))` way but why is the sibling selector `~` not working in JS but works in CSS?

I have this simple test case setup:

https://jsfiddle.net/jqdh4ruL/1/

```
<div>
  <textarea id="name" placeholder="Full Name">$This is a long text for full name</textarea>
  <pre></pre>
</div>


textarea ~ pre {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.372);
}

pre {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

var textarea = document.getElementById('name')
console.log(textarea.outerHTML)// returns the correct texture

console.log(textarea.parentNode.querySelector('pre'))//returns correct pre tag

console.log(textarea.querySelector('* ~ pre'))//returns null
```

Comment: `textarea.querySelector` only searches `textarea`'s children, since it has to children, it returns nothing. Try `document.querySelector` instead.

Comment: @HaoWu but then what's the point of the sibling selector using tilde `~`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Comment: You are looking for the  [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) pseudo class, except that it only works for self and inner drilling, not for siblings like you wish to do...

Comment: It's for searching elements with relative positions. If you want to get siblings of an element, try [`element.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) or `textarea.parentElement.querySelector('textarea ~ pre')` instead query its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document` instead of textarea, because when you use `textarea.querySelector()`, this can only select the children.

Also you can use `+` instead of `~`

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('name')
console.log(textarea.outerHTML)// returns the correct texture

console.log(textarea.parentNode.querySelector('pre'))//returns correct pre tag

console.log(document.querySelector('textarea + pre'))//returns correct pre tag
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="name" placeholder="Full Name">This is a long text for full name</textarea>
  <pre></pre>
</div>
```

UPDATE

> I am aware of the document way. I was just wondering why tilde can't work? then what's the point of the sibling selector using tilde ~? I read this and it seems to indicate it should work?

You can use `~` with query selector but the targeted element must be a children in that case

Here's a example when `~` works with `querySelector()`

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('name')
const div = document.querySelector('div')

console.log(div.querySelector('textarea + pre'))
console.log(div.querySelector('pre ~ pre'))
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="name" placeholder="Full Name">This is a long text for full name</textarea>
  <pre>+</pre>
  <div>text</div>
  <pre>~</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I am aware of the `document` way. I was just wondering why tilde can't work? then what's the point of the sibling selector using tilde `~`? I read this and it seems to indicate it should work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Comment: @PranoyC see u pdated answer

Comment: Ok. I just find it strange how `textarea ~ pre` works in CSS but not in JS?

Comment: You are not understanding the JS part, already explained and even give a working example with `~`. But to simplify again `~`  is for siblings (the equivalent for that in JS is `nextElementSibling`), the `querySelector()` is for children. in this case `pre` is a sibling, not a children of `textarea`

Comment: I get it now. I was missing this `descendant ` part: "returns the first element that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector